# Get value from promise using React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I was given a snippet of a class named GithubService. It has a method getProfile, returning a promise result, that apparently contains an object that I need to reach in my page component Github.

GithubService.ts

```
class GithubService {
  getProfile(login: string): Promise<GithubProfile> {
    return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(({ avatar_url, name, login }) => ({
        avatar: avatar_url as string,
        name: name as string,
        login: login as string,
      }));
  }    

export type GithubProfile = {
  avatar: string;
  name: string;
  login: string;
};

export const githubSerive = new GithubService();
```

The page component should look something like this:

```
import { githubSerive } from '~/app/github/github.service';

export const Github = () => {
  let name = 'Joshua';
  const profile = Promise.resolve(githubSerive.getProfile(name));
  return (
    <div className={styles.github}>
      <p>
        {//something like {profile.name}}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
```

};

I'm pretty sure the Promise.resolve() method is out of place, but I really can't understand how do I put a GithubProfile object from promise into the profile variable.
I've seen in many tutorials they explicitly declare promise methods and set the return for all outcomes of a promise, but I can't change the source code.

Comment: I can see you are using some kind of jsx, refer to js framework like React

Comment: make an async function in the component and then inside : const profile= await githubService.getProfile(name). Also check your spelling on your import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are using React, consider making use of the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hooks.

Your Code could then look like below, here's a working [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-feistel-3ijp47?file=/src/App.js:392-929) as well, I 'mocked' the GitHub service to return a profile after 1s.

```
export default function Github() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let name = "Joshua";
    const init = async () => {
      const _profile = await githubService.getProfile(name);
      setProfile(_profile);
    };
    init();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {profile ? (
        <div>
          <p>{`Avatar: ${profile.avatar}`}</p>
          <p>{`name: ${profile.name}`}</p>
          <p>{`login: ${profile.login}`}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>loading...</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the promise to be resolved by either using `async/await` or `.then` after the Promise.resolve.

```js
const profile = await githubSerive.getProfile(name);

const profile = githubSerive.getProfile(name).then(data => data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

```
import { githubSerive } from '~/app/github/github.service';

export async function Github() {
  let name = 'Joshua';
  const profile = await githubSerive.getProfile(name);
  return (
    <div className={styles.github}>
      <p>
        {profile.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if you are using react, things would be a little different (since you have tagged reactjs in the question):

```
import { githubSerive } from '~/app/github/github.service';
import * as React from "react";

export const Github = () => {
  let name = 'Joshua';
  const [profile, setProfile] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
       const profileData = await githubSerive.getProfile(name);
       setProfile(profileData);
    })();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={styles.github}>
      <p>
        {profile?.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```